# Do Palico Deviant weapons also have a special property?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

Weapons crafted from Deviant monsters charge up your Hunter Arts more quickly. Do Palico weapons crafted from Deviant monsters also charge up the support gauge more quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they are weapons like any other, and they don't provide special bonuses like their Hunter counterparts.